# Issues while using donut chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, patternfly

I am new to web development and am trying to use patternFly Donut chart for my project. But when I try to check it by running as simple HTML it throws below error. Could someone help me with this?

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vehTz.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>C3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/patternfly/3.24.0/css/patternfly.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/patternfly/3.24.0/css/patternfly-additions.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="donut-chart-6" class="example-donut-chart-utilization"></div>
    <script>
  var c3ChartDefaults = $().c3ChartDefaults();
  var utilizationDonutChartConfig = c3ChartDefaults.getDefaultDonutConfig('A');
  utilizationDonutChartConfig.bindto = '#donut-chart-6';
  utilizationDonutChartConfig.data = {
    type: "donut",
    columns: [
      ["Used", 60],
      ["Available", 40]
    ],
    groups: [
      ["used", "available"]
    ],
    order: null
  };
  utilizationDonutChartConfig.size = {
    width: 200,
    height: 171
  };

  utilizationDonutChartConfig.tooltip = {
    contents: $().pfGetUtilizationDonutTooltipContentsFn('MHz')
  };
  var utilizationDonutChart = c3.generate(utilizationDonutChartConfig);
  $().pfSetDonutChartTitle("#donut-chart-6", "60", "MHz Used");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is this "$().c3ChartDefaults();"

Comment: Dependency issue it seems. Try to check the order of the JS scripts you are using. Either some are missing, or the order is not as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `$()` is confusing. Commenting out the lines that use it yields a donut chart. It seems like you're trying to load default configurations, but I didn't find any information on the c3 website indicating that it was a jQuery plugin. Perhaps you're misunderstanding what jQuery does? If you're trying to load some sort of default configurations from a form as JSON then you [might need to get more creative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery).

For simplicity, in the example below I've reformatted your data as a single object.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>C3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/patternfly/3.24.0/css/patternfly.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/patternfly/3.24.0/css/patternfly-additions.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="donut-chart-6" class="example-donut-chart-utilization"></div>
    <script>
  //var c3ChartDefaults = $().c3ChartDefaults();
  //var utilizationDonutChartConfig = c3ChartDefaults.getDefaultDonutConfig('A');
  utilizationDonutChartConfig = {
    bindto : '#donut-chart-6',
    data : {
      type: "donut",
      columns: [
        ["Used", 60],
        ["Available", 40]
      ],
      groups: [
        ["used", "available"]
      ],
      order: null
    },
    size : {
      width: 200,
      height: 171
    },
   tooltip : {
    //contents: $().pfGetUtilizationDonutTooltipContentsFn('MHz')
    }
  }
  var utilizationDonutChart = c3.generate(utilizationDonutChartConfig);
  //$().pfSetDonutChartTitle("#donut-chart-6", "60", "MHz Used");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var c3ChartDefaults =  (<any>$()).c3ChartDefaults();
```

This worked for me.